# SQL select same column with different where, then join and append to outer query

Tags: sql, join, db2, subquery, udb

I am new to SQL. I have two tables, ***CarDesc*** and ***CarCost***. The ***CarDesc*** table drives the query population. I am trying to select the *CAR_DESC* column `where ID In List(1,2,3)` and then join on *ID* to the ***CarCost*** table to return a column for the *2D cost* and a column for the *4D cost*.

***CarDesc***

```
ID   CAR_DESC  COUNTRY
1    Toyota    Japan
2    Honda     Japan
3    Kia       Korea
4    Jeep      USA
5    Ford      USA
```

***CarCost***

```
ID   TYPE   COST
1    2D     3000
1    4D     2700
2    2D     4000
2    4D     5500
3    2D     3200
3    4D     5000
```

This is the expected result I am trying to receive: One distinct record for each car description and then a column for the *2D cost* and then a column for the *4D cost*

```
CAR_DESC 2D_COST  4D_COST
Toyota   3000     2700
Honda    4000     5500
Kia      3200     5000
```

I think I am close with the SQL, but I just keep getting different error messages as I tweak the code. Can you guys please help me with my SQL? This is what I have so far...

```
SELECT DESC 
FROM CarDesc
WHERE ID IN LIST (1,2,3)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COST AS 2D_COST
           WHERE TYPE = 2D)
     ON CarDesc.ID = CarCost.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COST AS 4D_COST
           WHERE TYPE = 4D)
     ON CarDesc.ID = CarCost.ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will would look something like this:

```
SELECT cd.*, cc2.cost as cost_2d, cc4.cost as cost_4d
FROM CarDesc cd LEFT JOIN
     CarCost cc2
     ON cd.Id = cc2.id AND cc2.TYPE = '2D' LEFT JOIN
     CarCost cc4
     ON cd.Id = cc4.id AND cc4.TYPE = '4D'
WHERE cd.ID IN (1, 2, 3);
```

You have numerous errors in your query.  It is not worth trying to explain them.  Examine this query to understand how it should work.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. This worked perfectly after adding  the table alias before the TYPE. It is probably simple to you, but you have seriously saved me a lot of time and headache. Much appreciated. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT cd.ID ,
 sum(case when cc.type='2D' then cc.cost else 0 end) 2D_COST,  
 sum(case when cc.type='4D' then cc.cost else 0 end) 4D_COST
 FROM CarDesc cd LEFT JOIN CarCost cc ON cd.Id = cc.id 
 WHERE cd.ID IN (1, 2, 3)
 group by cd.ID
```